# Refrescar de manera automática el contenido de un JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy intentando llevar un código en Java a una interfaz con JFrame, usando Neatbeans.

El punto de la interfaz es generar una tabla que se vaya modificando según los cambios en la matriz. Es decir, sería iniciar la interfaz, se muestra una simulación que trabaja sola y se termina al cerrar la interfaz.

Solo logro que funcione una vez, después no se refresca el contenido al mismo tiempo que se hace en la consola. De verdad no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

1. El método que llena y devuelve el `DefaultTableModel` y se le pasa como parámetro arreglo con que debería llenarse en cada ciclo es **`mostrar(SerVivo[][] Tablero)`** :

   ```
   DefaultTableModel LAtabla = new DefaultTableModel();
   String[][] interfaz = new String[50][50];
   for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<50; j++){
           /*comprueba cada espacio en el tablero segun el tipo de SerVivo
           y segun esto imprime en el espacio la letra que corresponda*/

           if (Tablero[i][j] instanceof Hormiga){
               interfaz[i][j] = "H";
           }
           else if(Tablero[i][j] instanceof OsoHormiguero){
               interfaz[i][j] = "OH";
           }
           else if(Tablero[i][j] instanceof Planta){
               interfaz[i][j] = "P";
           }
           else{
               interfaz[i][j] = " ";
           }
       }
   }

   LAtabla.setDataVector(interfaz, etiq_columnas);

   return LAtabla;
   ```
2. Posteriormente se llena la `JTable Tabla` con **`Tabla.setModel(mostrar(Tablero))`** en el método **`iniciar()`**:

   ```
   e = new Ecosistema(); 
   do{
       for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println("Dia:"+Dias);
       System.out.println("Hora:"+Horas);
       System.out.println();
       e.imprimirTablero();//Se muestra el proceso en consola

       Tabla.setModel(mostrar(e.Tablero));

       DiaLabel.setText(Integer.toString(Dias));
       HoraLabel.setText(Integer.toString(Horas));

       Activar();

       if(cont==48){
           cada48Segundos();
           cont=0;
       }

       cadaSegundo();
       esperarXSegundos(1);

       cont++;
       if(Horas==23){
           Horas=0;
           Dias++;
       }
       else{
           Horas++;
       }
       while(pausa){

       }
   }while(rsp!=0);
   ```

   }

**Aquí es donde ocurre el problema**, si logra entrar el en loop do_while,  entonces la interfaz se tranca y deja de funcionar. No imprime ni siquiera el contenido del primer ciclo. Solo funciona si antes de iniciar cambio el valor de `rsp = 0`

Este es el botón de inicio, que debería hace comenzar la simulación:

```
    private void IniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
       //Boton iniciar
        iniciar();
    }
```

Puedo lograr que la interfaz funcione eliminando el do_while del método `iniciar()`, y apretando el botón "Iniciar" para hacer cada iteración, pero quería saber la forma alternativa en la que:

- La tabla se refresque automáticamente en cada ciclo

o la otra alternativa

- Configurarla para que cada 1 segundo, por ejemplo, se refresque

Comment: Si bien la pregunta puede entenderse, ¿hay alguna forma de que presentes sólo los fragmentos importantes del código para reducir tu problema y facilitar la tarea de alguien que quiera ayudarte? Además, ¿qué hiciste hasta ahora para depurarlo? Quizás te sea útil leer cómo presentar un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que pasa es que cuando entra al while toda la interfaz se congela esto debido a que bloqueas el hilo de ejecución con el ciclo, una solución sencilla es poner el metodo iniciar en un Hilo o en un Timer si quieres controlar fácilmente cada cuanto se ejecuta la acción.

```
new Thread(){
        public void run() {
                iniciar();
        };
    }.start();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! No manejo muy bien hilos o timer. Debería implementarlo y entonces llamar al `Thread()` en el botón donde inicia la simulación: `private void IniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` ?

Comment: Si podría funcionar, algo importante es que el hilo solo se puede iniciar una vez. En el código que agregue primero se está creando el hilo y luego se está iniciando con el método .start(), eso hace que se ejecute el codigo que esta dentro del método run() pero sin bloquear la interfaz de usuario.

Comment: Funcionó. Inicié el `thread` creado con `thread.start();` en el botón de inicio y limpié la tabla al finalizar cada ciclo en el método `iniciar()`. Llevaba casi una semana tratando de conseguir la manera. Mil gracias!